# Why have a 1:1 Relationship - Database Design?

Tags: database-design, relationship, database-schema, one-to-one

I'm looking at an existing database schema and I'm a bit confused regarding the 1:1 realtionship in the example below:

```
Event
-----
id  int (PK)
Title varchar
Description varchar
OrganizerId int (FK)


EventSchedule
------------
id int (Pk)
EventId int (FK)
Start datetime
End   datetime
RepeatRule varchar (ical format for repeating events)  

Venue
-----
id int (PK)
EventId (FK)
Name  varchar
Address1 varchar
Address2 varchar
City varchar
Region varchar
Postcode varchar
latitude float
longitude float
```

An Event only ever takes place at one location so there is a 1:1 relationship between the Event and Venue. 
Similarly an Event has a 1:1 relationship with the EventSchedule - the ical repeat rule captures repeating events.

Would there be any reason or instance for separating tables like this? What would be wrong in having a single table as follows:

```
Event
-----
id int (PK)
Title varchar
Description varchar
OrganizerId int (FK)
Start datetime
End   datetime
RepeatRule varchar (ical format for repeating events) 
Venue  varchar
Address1 varchar
Address2 varchar
City varchar
Region varchar
Postcode varchar
latitude float
longitude float
```

Some advise on pros/cons of each design would be appreciated specifically in the above context to make the schema flexible enough for any future consideration though I can't possibly think of any reason where the above relations would ever change in a real world scenario i.e. 1:1 to 1:N etc.

Comment: The proposed schema seems more flexible and ready to accept most types of events, whereas yours seems highly specialized (I find it quite unlikely that venues will be used only once, and an event that takes place more than once doesn't seem uncommon to me either). So, the answer is, as so often, that the correct answer probably entirely depends on your use case...

Comment: As fvu mentioned, its unlikely that as a venue will only be used once. Its also best practice(3rd Normal Form) to separate all entity types. With a proper normalized database, future development and flexibility will be much easier. Also, you'll be able to eliminate complex quires when reporting on your data. If your events can occur more than once and at different venues, I would go as far as creating 3 tables. EventType(Event info like description, name, etc), Events(Relationship between venue and EventType, Dates, specific event detail etc.), and Venues.

Comment: @fvu The Venue table includes FK EventId, its a 1:1 relationship. An event cannot take place in multiple locations - if it was then it would be classed as a different event and a new record for that created. If there is another event that takes place at the same venue, a new record would be inserted into the Venue table with the same address details. So how would that be using the same venue? Similarly if an event takes place more than once, the details would be included inside the ical repeat rule i.e. there would be no need to create an row in the EventSchedule table for the same event.

Comment: @ozzii I overlooked the fact that Venue is tied to Event that way, that's very strange indeed. I would rather use a VenueId in Event. Wrt Eventschedule, what if an event gets repeated 4 times but with different start times, for example? In any case, the original structure seems to have serious issues.

Comment: @fvu why would you use VenueId in Event? An organizer fills in a form to create an event which would include providing Venue/address details. with your proposal, if that same venue record was used by different organizers for their events, what would happen if one of them decide to update the Venue/Address details. It would cascade to every other event using that VenueId - this would be bad.

Comment: ahhhh now I see - I saw your use case the other way around, and therefore now your proposal makes more sense.

Comment: @Ozzie, that would be good in most cases. But you coudl model correctly using a dat start stop , so that past events woudl maintain the old version of the address and new ones woudl use the current address.  And you couldl let them choose existing venues from a search.  That way if you have venues used previously, where teh data is known to be correct, you won't have them changed from a typo in data entry.

Comment: I'll point out that I have spent ten years working in databases that do meeting planning which is similar to event planning. I do know what gotchas you can run into.

Comment: @Helgm My understanding is that usually you separate into 1:1 is where you want a physical partition or where the additional data is expected to be unknown in which case you have a 1:0 or 1:1 or when you dont want to be hauling additional data around in queries. In the above an Event will always take place at a location and it will always require a start date. When doing a query for an event in most cases you will always require its venue details and start dates.

Comment: @HLGem what do you mean by adding a date start stop. It already has a start end date. Can you provide a schema to illustrate your suggestion please?

Comment: Hmmmm.  If I understand your subject matter correctly, more than one event can be scheduled for a Venue.  It's really a 1 to many relationship.

Answer (score 1):

One reason to separate is to avoid the use of nulls in the venue and schedule table if they are not known at the time the event record is set up.

Another reason to separate is that you have a one-to-one relationship now, but someone may be planning for a future when you don't have one-to-one relationship. I certainly have seen these types of things where events are in multiple locations and have multiple schedules.

And since venues are likely to be reused for different events, I would have designed a venue table and an EventVenue table to avoid repeating all the address and GPS data.

Another reason for separating may have to do with how the data is consumed. If you don't always need all the information in all of the queries sometimes it makes sense to spread them out to other tables.

Yet another reason for separating is that many people prefer to model based on what logically falls together.

Another reason for separating has to do with tables that are less wide tend to be faster to query (particularly if you don't need to always query the other information) and sometimes all the fields together makes for a table that is wider than the effective row size for a SQL Server record. If the max size of each field is met which that would cause you to be unable to add those records to that table even though SQL Server let you create it.

Comment: the use case is that an organizer when creating an event is required to provide a venue and address. I acknowledge venues can be resued for different events, but since different organizers are creating events, the same venueid/record can not be used for events that other organizers create. Otherwise, any time an organizer decides to edit the event and change the venue details, the change will cascade to every other event that is using the same venue id which woud not be the intended functionality. Note the venue/address is manually created by organizers. It's not a lookup table.

Comment: can you provide a schema for your suggestion about date start stop , so that past events would maintain the old version of the address and new ones would use the current address please

Comment: note the venue/address/gps is done using google address lookup. Storing them in a venue table to avoid repeating all the address/gps data wouldn't fulfill any functional business requirement, since it it unlikely to be used as a lookup table becuase it would only contain addresses for previously created event. Wiring it up as a lookuptable along with google address search would serve no purpose. I think you are soley looking at this from a database perspective rather than an actual real world functional application.

Answer (score 1):

One reason to have two tables in a 1:1 relationship is if the relationship is optional.  For example, if an Event can exist with no event schedule.  This might better be described as one to zero or one.  In this case, a simple join gets rid of the unscheduled events.  This is a whole lot easier than wrestling with NULLS.

The performance considerations are secondary in this case, and could go either way, depending on how you use the data.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons I can think of, to normalize the table is such a way:

1. You have some ORM that operates on EventSchedule/Venue, and only seldom you're interested in event name, for example
2. Migrations are faster that way. Think that you have 1M rows, and need to add another row to your Event table from the proposed solution. Your migration will lock the table for a very long time. Migrating tables with fewer rows is faster.

Comment: If i'm using entityframework and have a form to create/edit an event (the form would display fields from all 3 tables) I would have to update 3 tables, increasing the level of complexity without any real value. If I'm doing queries to search for event by location and dates I'm having to add additional joins, again without any real benefit? You mention migrations and performance but fail to consider that all 3 tables will have equal number of rows - its 1:1 relationship. If I add a row to the event table, the business rules dictate there needs to be a corresponding row in the other two tables.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another reason: in a micro-services architecture you might have multiple services that are each responsible for different activities, such as events and schedules.

Each one would be better isolated if they had their own tables, with messaging between the services being used to communicate required data.